# OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED error when start navigation for transport mode RouteOptions.TransportMode.BICYCLE

Tags: android, here-api, here-maps-rest

I am integrating Here's premium SDK for Android to do a navigation test for a calculated route.
I have the following issue that I hope that somebody can help me.  I configure the route itinerary from map and calculate routes fine but When I start navigation for this calculated route in this map the following error ocurre: **NavigationManager.Error.OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED**

The code is the folowing:

```
override fun startNavigationForRouteInMap(
        route: Route,
        map: com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map,
        voiceSkinSelected: VoiceSkin?) {

        navigationManager.apply {
            setMap(map)
            voiceGuidanceOptions.voiceSkin = voiceSkinSelected
            /*
             * Set the map update mode to ROADVIEW.This will enable the automatic map movement based on
             * the current location.If user gestures are expected during the navigation, it's
             * recommended to set the map update mode to NONE first. Other supported update mode can be
             * found in HERE Android SDK API doc
            */
            mapUpdateMode = NavigationManager.MapUpdateMode.ROADVIEW
            addNavigationManagerEventListener(
                WeakReference<NavigationManager.NavigationManagerEventListener>(
                    navigationManagerEventListener)
            )
            addPositionListener(
                WeakReference<NavigationManager.PositionListener>(positionListener))
            addManeuverEventListener(
                WeakReference<NavigationManager.ManeuverEventListener>(routeManeuverEventListener))

        }

        val result = navigationManager.simulate(route, 60)

        if(result == NavigationManager.Error.NONE)
            navigationListener?.onNavigationStarted(route)
        else {
            Log.d("NAVIGATION", "Error name -> ${result.name}")
            navigationListener?.onNavigationError()
        }
```

Why ocurred this error? I have configured the correct api key and license key.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Navigation with BICYCLE is probably not enabled for your licensekey, you would need to get in touch with your HERE Sales Contact to have this enabled. If you don't have a Sales Contact, please use the [Form](https://developer.here.com/help#how-can-we-help-you) available on HERE developer portal.